# Can we write the right hand side as a one integral formula? (A lecture on multivariable mathematics by Theodore Shifrin on YouTube)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, iterated-integrals

I am watching a lecture on multivariable mathematics by Theodore Shifrin on YouTube.

I want to know the answer to [this problem](https://youtu.be/miSfMprNByQ?t=2727).

My answer is the following. My answer uses two integral formulae.

> $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-x}\int_{0}^{x+y} f(x,y,z)\,dz\,dy\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{z}\int_{z-x}^{1-x} f(x,y,z)\,dy\,dx\,dz+\int_{0}^{1}\int_{z}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-x} f(x,y,z)\,dy\,dx\,dz.$$

Can we write the right hand side as a one integral formula like this?

> $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-x}\int_{0}^{x+y} f(x,y,z)\,dz\,dy\,dx=\int_{*}^{*}\int_{*}^{*}\int_{*}^{*} f(x,y,z)\,dy\,dx\,dz.$$

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer [in the next lecture](https://youtu.be/exmZ4nuWGM4?t=1264).
And my answer was right!

Comment: If you are done, then close or delete the answer.

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari I disagree. tchappy ha should *accept* their own answer, but leave the question in case someone has more to add

Comment: @Mark Understandable.